# my virtual environment cannot be found

Tags: windows-10, bash, git-bash, virtualenv

I'm on a PC windows 10 and always open git bash, then `source activate my-env` and open a jupyter notebook; somehow my-env broke and I get this error:

> "C:\bld\conda_1565126647711_h_env/etc/profile.d/conda.sh: No such
>   file or directory"

Also, I cannot activate "my-env" in a jupyter notebook and I'm getting a "kernal error" in jupyter; but I am able to activate the environment from command prompt.

I've tried:

- typing the entire file path into bash
- deleting the env in bash
- deleting the env from command prompt (still can activate it from CMD)
- opening jupyter from CMD; still get the kernal error there
- `echo ". C:\Users\mngav\Anaconda3\etc\profile.d\conda.sh" >> ~\.bashrc` which worked for a colleague but was not successful for me.

Should I just hard reset my comp and set up the environment form scratch?

Comment: Before you reinstall Windows, to solve a Anaconda problem, I would simply reinstall Python and Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I'm by no means good at this, but I think I figured out a work-around.

In the "activate" file located `H:\anaconda3\Scripts\activate`
I first changed the path in `_CONDA_ROOT`to point to my conda folder `H:\anaconda3` in my case. (I have no idea what the bld paths are for but that's what messed things up for me)

Then in the file `H:\anaconda3\etc\profile.d\conda.sh` I changed `export CONDA_EXE` to point to my conda.exe location; `H:\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe`

Then in git bash I was able to use `source activate myenv` and it seems to be working fine again.

This issue happened to me after updating my anaconda navigator. I was hoping that would not mess up my normal workflow of using git bash for most things but I guess it did.

P.S. I was not able to use `source activate` in the windows `command prompt` but conda activate works. Not sure if this is related though.